# cast List object to new object extending List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to generate a custom xml doc, using this class:

```
[CollectionDataContract(Name="Applications", ItemName="Application")]
public class ApplicationNamesList : List<string> { }
```

The xml output im aming at should look like this

```
<Applications>
    <Application>...</Application>
    <Application>...</Application>
    <Application>...</Application>
</Applications>
```

But once I have a `List<string>` object and try and cast this to `ApplicationNamesList` i get an `InvalidCastException`.

Is there something basic im not getting here?

Comment: Something basic: You have a class A that inherits from B. You have an instance of B but you expect to be able to cast it to an A. That's the opposite way around to how inheritance works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<string>` simply isn't a `ApplicationNamesList`. You would need to do something like this:

```
var result = new ApplicationNamesList();
result.AddRange(list);
```

With `list` being a `List<string>`.

Sometimes it helps to use real world examples:

Every Porsche ( => `ApplicationNamesList`) is a car ( => `List<string>`). But not every car is a Porsche.

Comment: Ok, Im just gonna enrole in school once again.

Comment: +1 for Porsche example